Get value of header in WSO2 Micro Integrator endpoint response
We have an HTTP endpoint of WSO2 Micro Integrator. This mediator points to an REST API that returns a 201 message with a validation token (it is a login sequence). The token is not included in the JSON body, but in a special custom header of the response message (called X-Subject_Token). How can I get this header of the response?
Thanks in advance
In fact, I have obtained values of JSON body fields easily, but I cannot see any procedure to do the same with headers values. Browsing official documentation gave no result, as well as search in the Internet. Therefore, no tries so far, as I do not know how to start.

You can use the get-property('transport','HEADER_NAME') expression to get any header value. In your case it will be as follows,
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:5000/api/pet1"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
<property name="TOKEN_HEADER" expression="get-property('transport','X-Subject_Token')"/>
<log category="INFO" level="custom">
    <property name="TOKEN_HEADER" expression="$ctx:TOKEN_HEADER"/>
</log>

For more information about the expressions and scopes, refer the documentation https://mi.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/synapse-properties/scopes/#transport-scope

This works. Thank you very much for your help
